# Facebook's modified DAU & MAU public app metrics

Tags: facebook-insights

On January 2013, Facebook had changed the way the publicly reported DAU and MAU figures are interpreted. Instead of reporting exact MAU & DAU figures per app, Facebook started categorizing each app into a MAU & DAU tiers, thus reported MAU & DAU numbers are rounded into tiers (or levels). Facebook has also introduced a new approach to metrics: ranks - that indicates how well an application is performing against all other apps. (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/01/09/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/ and see also http://www.appdata.com/understanding_facebook_ranks)

My question is this:

Indeed when I check Farmville2's usage metrics by visiting https://graph.facebook.com/321574327904696 I do see the new approach. i.e: DAU and MAU reported figures are rounded up into tiers. No exact figures as before January. See below, MAU is reported in the 10 million tier, DAU reported as above 1 million, i.e: 1m tier.

results:

```
{
   "id": "321574327904696",
   "name": "FarmVille 2",
   "description": "Grow and harvest beautiful crops, raise adorable animals, and craft delicious treats on your very own lifelike 3D farm.",
   "category": "Games",
   "subcategory": "Simulation",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=321574327904696",
   "namespace": "farmville-two",
   "icon_url": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc7/v85005/104/321574327904696/app_2_321574327904696_1179950008.gif",
   "logo_url": "http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc7/v85005/104/321574327904696/app_1_321574327904696_637315223.gif",
   "company": "Zynga Inc.",
   "daily_active_users": "1000000",
   "weekly_active_users": "5000000",
   "monthly_active_users": "10000000",
   "daily_active_users_rank": 4,
   "monthly_active_users_rank": 1
}
```

However if I use Facebook Graph API explorer and issue FQL query like the one below about Farmville2's usage, I still see its exact MAU & DAU figures, not the approximate MAU & DAU tier level to which the app belongs to.

i.e:

```
SELECT metric, value
FROM insights WHERE object_id='321574327904696' AND metric='application_active_users' AND period=period('month') AND end_time=end_time_date('2013-01-20')
```

results in showing a MAU of 41,848,270. If I query about DAU, I will get 8,264,964.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "metric": "application_active_users", 
      "value": 41848270
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is this:

which DAU & MAU figures should I take into consideration? Are the exact figures reported by querying the Insights table still there for just a short period of time as a result of wanting to be backward compatible and are soon to be removed? Should I assume I cannot get exact DAU and MAU numbers any longer?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably assume you won't be able to get exact DAU and MAU numbers soon.  The numbers you get from the Graph API are the correct results, and the FQL query sounds like it hasn't been migrated to the new app metrics yet.

I would recommend that you only use the Graph API metrics into consideration as the exact figures returned by FQL might be changed in the near future.  I recommend creating a bug report on our [bug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) and updating your answer here on SO with the link to the bug report so that others can track the status of this issue.  Also, reference this SO thread in the bug report so we can take a look at this.

Comment: Jesse, thanks so much for your quick answer, I really appreciate it.  I will go ahead and follow your guidelines. Just one more quick question: By querying using FQL I am able to specify date for which I would like to get metrics for (see above, end_time=). Using the graph API it seems I can't specify a date, just get the metrics for the current time being. Is that correct? Any way around that?

Comment: I believe that with the new app metrics, there won't be a way to specify a date since we've changed it to show DAU/MAU tiers instead of exact numbers.  Reporting the issue with the bug tool is a guarantee to get an official response, however.